# Largest prime known to ancients

Tags: prime-numbers, math-history, prime-factorization

As is well known, Fermat couldn't check the primality of $F_{5} = 2^{2^{5}} + 1$. This raises an interesting question : what was the largest prime number that was known to ancients (particularly Greeks) or the mathematicians till Fermat and how much efforts were made to find the larger and larger primes? I couldn't find any authentic answer to this question so far and I would be quite grateful if I get a good answer to this question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: At least *some* of the interest today in discovering large primes (or computing more and more digits of $\pi$) is more aimed at testing computer hardware/software than the results themselves. This incentive would be lacking for the good old days ... Also, what would have been the advantage of knowing that 7919 is the 1000th prime, for instance? Then again, apparently in Gauß' times, enough small primes were known to dare nice conjectures - but this again is not fully related to record-breaking primes ...

Comment: Euclid's proof that there are an infinite number of primes made finding larger and larger ones a lot less interesting.

Comment: I suspect then as now it was a Mersenne prime. Look up some old misconceptions about perfect numbers, that would give important clues for this question.

Comment: This is what Wikipedia thinks: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_known_prime_number

Comment: @CountIblis: though the search for the "most uninteresting prime number" remains an interesting challenge.

Answer (score 2):

There are, up to Fermat's contemporary Mersenne, many lists in which perfect numbers were listed. Most of them contained the "prime" number $2^{11}-1$, many of them even $2^9 - 1$. It does not make much sense to me to ask for the largest known prime in such a situation.

Also I am surprised to hear that it is well known that Fermat could not check the primality of $F_5$. It is clear that he either *did* not or that he made a mistake, but there's nothing that would have prevented him to find the divisor 641. Euler verified the primality of $2^{31}-1$, and from then on lists of records do make some sense.